# Detecting rising and falling edge via SQL (loading cycles)

Tags: sql, detection, cycle

i need to detect rising and falling edges from a loading state in my logs and need to list all loading cycles.

Lets say i have a table LOG

```
UTS        | VALUE | STATE

1438392102 | 1000  | 0
1438392104 | 1001  | 1
1438392106 | 1002  | 1
1438392107 | 1003  | 0
1438392201 | 1007  | 1
1438392220 | 1045  | 1
1438392289 | 1073  | 0
1438392305 | 1085  | 1
1438392310 | 1090  | 1
1438392315 | 1095  | 1
```

And need all cycles where STATE = 1
I need to know when they started how long they lasted
and how much VALUE changed in each cycle.

I also might have a situation where the last cycle isn't
finished yet.

Do you have an idea how i can do this in SQL in a 
good performing way ? Cuz i might run into situations
where my logs return several hundred of thausends of rows.

Thanks for help

Comment: Please tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: Sorry you know we using this mess of a maxdb aka sapdb and there are no tags for that.